# UIButton is not registering touches

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift3

I added UIButton with custom image and no text to Navigation Bar in one of my View Controllers. In that Navigation bar is also default button Back.

I connected that UIButton with Connection: Action, Type: UIButton, Event: Touch Up Inside and Arguments: Sender.

When I click on that button nothing happens, it's not registering touch at all. Button Back is working normally.

[image]

Why is this happening? How to fix it?

Comment: you did not take a photo, I suspect the `button's` size you did not set , and it may be too small

Comment: It's not to small. Size is 35x35. You can see it clearly.

Comment: can you take the photo in your post?

Comment: Are you adding it via `navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(myButton)` or `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = UIBarButtonItem(customView: myButton)`?

Comment: @paulvs I just dragged it in `Main.storyboard` to Navigation Bar and then connected it with `View Controller` just like you normally connect button.

Comment: Change the background color of your button and check is it visible in your controller or not

Comment: @Rajat It is visible, I tested it. Button image is white, I set background gradient color in code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Since you are adding it to navigation bar it must be a `UIBarButtonItem`. So the action outlet you are connecting to it must have a type `UIBarButtonItem` and not `UIButton`.
2. Check if the outlet of the `UIBarButtonItem` is connected properly.
3. Check if the user interaction of `UIBarButtonItem` is enabled.

Comment: I can't drag `UIBarButtonItem` to `Navigation Bar` in that `View Controller`. I can only drag `UIBarButtonItem` to main `Navigation Bar`. If `Navigation Bar` has Back button I can't drag `UIBarButtonItem` to it in `Main.storyboard`.

Comment: Yes because UIBarButtonItem is only meant to be added to bars and not anywhere else. But still you can drag and drop its outlet in the view controller class.

Answer (score 0):

> When I click on that button nothing happens, it's not registering touch at all.

99% of the time when I see this complaint, the reason is that you've somehow placed the button outside its superview. A button outside its superview is visible (by default) but not touchable. (Sometimes this happens because the superview itself has never been given a size and so has zero size; other times it is for some other reason.)

I can't tell you any more because *you* didn't tell any more (i.e. you didn't give details of how this button is getting into the navigation bar). But I'm willing to bet that if you dig deeper you'll find that my guess is right.

Comment: Hi, I just dragged that button to navigation bar in Main.storyboard and set constraints, height and width. I added image so you could better see how it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by first adding Navigation Item to Navigation Bar and then adding Button to Navigation Item.

Answer (score 0):

To add button on navigation bar you have to add like this:

```
 let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "abc", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.buttonClicked(_:)))
 let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
 navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image.png"))
 navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
```

This is for left button. You can add right button in the same way.